# Android SDK External library

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, external, libraries

I have a big problem. I just re-formatted my computer and re-installed Eclipse and Android SDK (the latest) and all of a sudden my projects crash every time the apps try to use an external library.

I have been using this external library for the past 6 months without any problems, but now the apps crash as soon as its called. All my apps depend on it, and all the apps i developed are crashing when deployed.

I installed an older version of eclipse thinking it might have caused it, but turns out that wasnt it.

Which lead me to believe that it is caused by the latest Android SDK. What could be causing this, and how can i fix it? please help.

The external library I am using is Zip4J an unzipper.  http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php

Comment: What do you mean by crash...?? whats the error ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9816673/544198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When including external libraries you must put the jar in a `libs` folder in your project now. You may also need to right click the jar file and add to build path.

Or if it is an android library, you need to include it in your `project.properties` file. Or you can add it through a wizard using eclipse. Project properties -> Android -> Add library.